# Is there anything special I have to think of when setting post_date_gmt when inserting a new post?

Tags: date, wp-insert-post

I'm inserting information from a user into a custom post type. `$current_user` it a user-object.

Is there anything special I have to think of when setting `post_date_gmt` when inserting a new post with wp_insert_post? (Or could I just fetch the value from the user-table like below?

```
$pupil = array(
              'post_title'      => $current_user->display_name,
              'post_date'       => $current_user->user_registered,
              'post_date_gmt'   => $current_user->user_registered,
              'post_type'       => 'pupil',
              'post_status'     => 'private',                     //This registration cpt is not available for public
              'post_author'     => $current_user->ID
            );
            $postid_pupil = wp_insert_post( $pupil )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the times, you can just leave it empty and the wp_insert_post will take care of handling it but if you want to set it use php's function:

```
gmdate("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime($current_user->user_registered))
```

which works exactly like the php date function.

Comment: gmdate("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($current_user->user_registered))

Answer (score 2):

> post_date_gmt

As the name suggest it is date time in [GMT](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/). [GMT(Greenwich Mean Time)](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/) is a timezone.

*`wp_insert_post`*  internally converts post_date into GMT using *`get_gmt_from_date`* . So if you don't pass it, it will do it for you.

Or you can use

```
'post_date_gmt'=>get_gmt_from_date($current_user->user_registered);
```

to convert your date to GMT.